# How to replace second character from lowercase to uppercase in a string

Tags: jquery, string

Here is the problem. I am getting a string from backend and want to replace two letters in uppercase. Below is the code:

```
var query = "WHERE account >= 23 || company != null;";
var slicedQuery = query.slice(7);

slicedQuery = slicedQuery.replace(slicedQuery.charAt(slicedQuery.lastIndexOf(";")), "");

var firstChar = slicedQuery.charAt(0);
slicedQuery = slicedQuery.replace(firstChar, firstChar.toUpperCase());

if(slicedQuery.indexOf("|") >= 0) {

    var charInCondition = slicedQuery.charAt(slicedQuery.indexOf("|") + 3);

    slicedQuery = slicedQuery.replace(charInCondition, charInCondition.toUpperCase());
}
```

The 'a' of account is replaced correctly with 'A'. But the 'c' of company is not getting replaced. Instead the 'c' in Acconut is getting replaced with 'C'. Please tell how to do this. Help!

Comment: is that JS making SQL queries? that sounds soo bad

Comment: @kennypu try to understand how much easier it is for a user to fire-up developer tools, firebug etc. change IDs and have all the freedom. just kidding.... it is very-very bad.

Comment: code might be just generating the query through jquery and will be processed later in a servlet? but it will still be bad in that case and may be susceptible to hacks

Comment: Please add an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**

Function `replace` will replace **only the first** occurence of its first argument. Your code correctly recognises it must replace the 'c' (from "company"), but calling `replace` changes the first occurence of 'c' (in "account") only.

---

**The solution**

You need to replace the code inside your `if` block with this:

```
var idx = slicedQuery.indexOf("|") + 3;
var charToReplace = slicedQuery.charAt(idx);
slicedQuery = slicedQuery.substring(0, idx)
              + slicedQuery.substring(idx).replace(
        charToReplace, charToReplace.toUpperCase());
```

(BTW are you sure it should be `.slice(7)` and not `.slice(6)` ?)

Comment: Thanks a lot ExpertSystem.For understanding my problem correctly and solving it. Its working perfectly now. Thanks again.